# CosmosDB + MongoAPI, updating document workaround?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-cosmosdb

I've been trying to simply update a CosmosDB document via the mongodb api in my node application, I've been testing in and out, no errors but the value does not update no matter what.

I know updating array elements is not supported which is fine, but this is a top-level key-value pair. Changes simply don't happen with no error whatsoever.

I've been following the Mean.js project with uses CosmosDB + Mongoose + Node + Angular, looking at the API for updating hero and trying some of that code but it still doesn't update.

I've been reading the documentation trying to figure out the default way of handling CRUD operations within CosmosDB and which parts of the MongoAPI it supports but so far no luck.

For tests purposes, I'm using this code:

```
async function updateUser(id) {
    try {
        let user = await User.findById(id);

        console.log (id);
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) return
        user.id = id
        user.firstName = 'ASDASDASASDASDASDASDASDA'

        const result = await user.save()
        console.log(result);     
    }    
    catch(err) {
        console.log("There was an error updating user", err);
    }
}
```

So, I've been playing around some more and managed to update a hero using this code:

```
updateHero('10')

async function updateHero(id) {    
    const originalHero = {
        uid: id,
        name: 'Hero2',
        saying: 'nothing'
      };
    Hero.findOne({ uid: id }, (error, hero) => {

    hero.name = originalHero.name;
    hero.saying = originalHero.saying;
    hero.save(error => {
      return(hero);
      console.log('Hero updated successfully!');
    });
  });
}
```

Now I'm just not sure why this has actually worked and why it hasn't before. The main thing that is different is that I'm using an 'uid' instead of the actual ID assigned by CosmosDB.

Comment: It would help to have specific details. Can you please edit your question to show the code you're using, to do your updates (as well as some representative data)? Also, does the update fail both through Mongoose *and* through direct `db.collection.update()`? And with the latter, what does the result output look like? (the mongo client should show you how many documents were updated)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Updated with the piece of code, first time I'm hearing about db.collection.update()  -- will look for the documentation around it.

Comment: I really can't see what's going on, from that, and you haven't shown what's in `result` after the update. But: 1) you shouldn't be trying to change a document's id; 2) Please try updating a document via the MongoDB shell (`mongo`) so you can see exactly what's going on. This will avoid all potential issues around Mongoose and the rest of your code stack, so that you can see the exact results of the operation

Comment: @DavidMakogon - wasn't trying to update the ID, just to find a document by ID and then update some other stuff in that document, the problem is there's nothing in the result object, that's why I haven't posted. No error no nothing. And the document stayed the same. But I have pieced together something that works from the Mean.js PUT example and it seems to work so far, I have updated the original post with that code.

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: @JayGong my code was simply wrong, found the syntax that was compatible with CosmosDB + got a bunch of other workarounds/solutions around here.

Comment: @Jdoe Sorry,not sure what workarounds you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested sample code you provided and they both updated document successfully.

Sample document:

[image]

Snippet One:

```
updateUser('5b46eb0ee1a2f12ea0af307f')

async function updateUser(id) {

    try {

    let user = await Family.findById(id);

    console.log (id);
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) return
    user.id = id
    user.name = 'ASDASDASASDASDASDASDASDA'

    const result = await user.save()
    console.log(result); 
    }

    catch(err) {
        console.log("There was an error updating user", err);
    }
}
```

Output One:

[image]

[image]

Snippet Two:

```
updateFamily('5b46eb0ee1a2f12ea0af307f')

async function updateFamily(id) {

    const updateFamily = {
        _id: id,
        name: 'ABCD',
    };
    Family.findOne({ _id : id }, (error, family) => {
        family.name = updateFamily.name;
        family.save(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(family));
            console.log('Hero updated successfully!');
            return(family);
        });
    });
}
```

Output Two:

[image]

[image]

In addition, you could use `db.collection.update()` to update document.

```
db.families.update(
   { _id: '5b46eb0ee1a2f12ea0af307f' },{ $set:
      {
        name: 'AAAA'
      }
   })
```

More details,please refer to the doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Hope it helps you.